# What should appear in "Full Disk Access" by default?

Tags: security, settings, malware

I am looking for malware in my computer. I found that "Security & Privacy – Full Disk Access" is allowed for certain objects like "launchd" however I do not know what should be here in the first place. How many items are usually in there?

Comment: I think that a clean install will have nothing in there. But bear in mind that it isn't really "Full (Unbridled) Disk Access". It mostly covers certain user data, like Mail, Messages and TM backups. Also for some 'whole-of-disk' tasks like disk utilities.   I've got 30 items or so.

Comment: I doubt any system process needs to be in there. Nothing would work if launchd couldn't operate without additional user perms. The pref is for user-level stuff, antiviruses, Onyx, AppCleaner, EasyFind, TechTool, DaisyDisk etc - things that need to be able to use the whole disk to do their job.

Comment: @Tetsujin do you think that in principle I could remove everything from the list? Later each app should ask for permission if truly needed right?

Comment: @benwiggy same question

Comment: If you're looking for malware, then I would just use an app like Malwarebytes to scan your disk for known malware, rather than spending time worrying whether all kinds of folders and settings might be malware or not. If you recognise the apps in the list, and they do indeed need to access the disk (e.g. the kind of utilities mentioned by @Tetsujin,) then leave them there.